# How to open an excel workbook with path and file name as changing parameters

Tags: excel, vba

I am new with VBA and I am struggling when trying to run a simple command.

I want to open a workbook (*name = test.xlsx*) which is saved in a specific path (*C:\Users\u16086\Desktop\Folder*) in my PC with a VBA code.

I defined two names in my first excel that are two parameters that I can modify if the path or the name of the file is different:

**path**: C:\Users\u16086\Desktop\Folder

**file_name**: test.xlsx

The code I wrote is:

```
Option Explicit

Sub openworksheet()
    Dim path As String
    Dim file_name As String
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=path & file_name
End Sub
```

I ran the code, but it says there’s an error *run-time error1004*. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Try `Workbooks.Open Filename:=path & "\" & file_name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined two variables. You must allocate values to them and then build the path as shown below:

```
Sub openworksheet()
    Dim path As String
    Dim file_name As String
    path = "C:\Users\u16086\Desktop\Folder"
    file_name = "test.xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open fileName:=path & "\" & file_name
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry. just saw your answer... BTW you have a typo in path :)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout: No any problem! He will better learn the code idea... :) And yes, I only copied what he had in the question. Corrected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The path `C:\Users\u16086\Desktop\Folder\test.xlsx` can also be written as

```
"C:\Users\u16086\Desktop\Folder" & "\" & "test.xlsx"
```

so try

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=path & "\" & file_name
```

Alternatively, you can check if the folder path ends with "\" or not. For example

```
Option Explicit

Sub openworksheet()
    Dim path As String
    Dim file_name As String

    '~~> Change Sheet name and cell address accordingly
    path = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    file_name = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value

    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=path & file_name
End Sub
```